Как вызвать конвейерную функцию? ORA-06553: PLS-306: ошибочно число или типы аргументов при обращении к 'GET_ZP'
is
type kol_dep is record (sum_sal          number,
                        min_sal          number,
                        max_sal          number,
                        names varchar2(1000),
                        dep_id          number);
    type kol_dep_tb is table of kol_dep;
    
    v_kol_dep_tb kol_dep_tb;
    function get_zp (proc_tbl kol_dep_tb) return kol_dep_tb pipelined;
    end pkg_agg_employees;
    
    ---------TELO PAKETA-------
    
    create or replace package body pkg_agg_employees
    is

function get_zp (proc_tbl kol_dep_tb) return kol_dep_tb pipelined
     is
     v_report_row kol_dep;
     
     cursor c_dep
     is
     select e.department_id as dep,
    sum(e.salary)sum_sal,
    min(e.salary)min_sal,
    max(e.salary)max_sal,
    listagg(e.first_name||' '||e.last_name|| ', '||chr(10))within group (order by e.last_name) as names
    from employees e
    inner join departments dep
    on e.department_id=dep.department_id
    inner join jobs j
    on e.job_id=j.job_id
    group by e.department_id
    order by e.department_id;
         begin
         for r in c_dep loop
        v_report_row:=null;
v_report_row.dep_id:=r.dep;
v_report_row.sum_sal:=r.sum_sal;
v_report_row.min_sal:=r.min_sal;
v_report_row.max_sal:=r.max_sal;
v_report_row.names:=r.names;
         pipe row (v_report_row);
         end loop;
         return;
         close c_dep;
end get_zp;
end pkg_agg_employees;```






не понимаю куда вставить 




 ```DECLARE
v_table pkg_agg_employees.kol_dep_tb;

BEGIN
  v_table := pkg_agg_employees.kol_dep_tb();
  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(pkg_agg_employees.get_zp(v_table));
END; ```
или как по-другому исправить эту ошибку?

